# how to get last td text box value and many textboxs in td are hidden.and both the appended tables dont has same number of td's

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "table .view", function() {
    if ((b.serial_no) == "") {
        $('.recptdt').append('' + i + '' + b.item_type + '' + b.item_name + '' + b.model_no + '' + b.unit + '' + b.receipt_qty + '');
    }
    $.each(data.response.mod_ser_less, function(a, b) {
        $('.recptdt').append('' + i + '' + b.item_type + '' + b.item_name + '' + b.unit + '' + b.req_qty + '');
    });

});
```

**And now i tried to get values like**

```
$(".issuqantity").each(function() {

    //var textbox1 = $(this).next().find('.issuqantity').val(); 
    //var textbox1 =$(this).find(':last-child').val(); 
    var textbox1 = $(this).find('.booksqty').val(); //alert(textbox1); 
    var textbox2 = $(this).val();
    //alert(parseInt(textbox1) > parseInt(textbox2)); 
    var inte1 = parseInt(textbox1);
    var inte2 = parseInt(textbox2);
    //alert(inte1); 
    //alert(inte2) 
    //return false; 
    //if($("#indent_req_qty").val() != $("#recqantity").val()) 
    if ((inte2) > (inte1)) {
        alert("Issue.Qty should not be graterthan Req.Qty");
        return false;
    }
});
```

help me!What is wrong in it.And i was new to this site and jquery.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide your html code?

Comment: <div class ="form-group" >
         <table class ="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover copytabl">
          <thead>
           <tr id = "gridview" >
            <th>conformation </th>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Item Type</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Serial.No</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class = "recptdt">
          </tbody> 
         </table>
       </div>

Comment: Finally came up with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change',".recqantity",function (){ //to compare issue qty !> req.qty
    var reqc_qty =$(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().children().val();
    //alert(reqc_qty);
    var issuee_qty = $(this).val();
    //alert(issuee_qty);
    var inte1 = parseInt(reqc_qty);
    var inte2 = parseInt(issuee_qty);
    //alert (inte1);
    if( (inte2) > (inte1))
    {
        alert("Issue.Qty should not be Grater than Req.Qty");

        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```